# 403 response after deploying an elasticbean stack Javawith tomcat8 enviorement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running into this weird issue that I never seen before and wondering if someone can shed some light.

So I deployed an elastic beanstack enviorement with tomcat8/Java8 as the platform.

I uploaded the war file, accessed the box via SSH all is well, deployed the mysql server, build my tables and what not, everything is functional. However, the issue is when I send a request by postman I get the following response:

{

"status": 403,

"error": "Forbidden",

"message": "Access Denied",

"path": "/nav-insider-api/users/login"

}

The weird thing is that I have an EC2 instance running on it's own without a EB environment and it does function without any problems. I hit that API and it returns a valid response for me. Same DB same war file and same version of tomcat8.

I couldn't really think of much but to check the Elasticbeanstack logs and the below caught my attention - if so what could be causing it? I never seen it before even in my line of work.

`[Mon Apr 20 03:29:19.380050 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 3998:tid 140415550347008] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed`

`[Mon Apr 20 03:29:19.380090 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3998:tid 140415550347008] [client 162.243.131.92:55570] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost`

Comment: Connection refused usually means that the security group isn't allowing any traffic in that port. EB usually allows traffic on 80 by default, if you're using 8080, did you allow ingress traffic on that port?

Comment: I changed the port on both the EC2 instance and the tomcat configurations.